# Assign records count to variable from string command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 `nvarchar` variables which each contains commands.

1. variable

```sql
    DECLARE @ResourceClause AS nvarchar(MAX) = N'
    from CleneniPzs cp
```

2. variable which calls 1. nvarchar

```sql
     DECLARE @Query AS nvarchar(MAX) = N'
     select * from (SELECT
       distinct cp.Id
     ' + @ResourceClause + N'
     ) as sq
     ORDER BY ' + STUFF((SELECT N', ' + cs.SortColumn + N' ' +  cs.OrderColumn FROM @ColumnSort cs FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') +
     IIF(@s IS NOT NULL, N' OFFSET ' + cast(@p * @s as nvarchar(255)) + N' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + cast(@s as nvarchar(255)) + N' ROWS ONLY', N'')
```

I need to assign total count of records which return 2.nvarchar to my variable `@totalCount`

something like(this is bad)

```
select @totalCount = count(*) from @Query
```

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temp table and `SP_executesql`, something like the following:

```
Create Table #Temp
(
    ColumnOne int,
    ColumnTwo Nvarchar(250),
    ColumnThree DateTime
)

DECLARE @Query AS nvarchar(MAX) = N'
    Insert into #Temp
     select 
         CoulmnOne,
         CoulmnTwo,
         CoulmnThree 
     from (SELECT
       distinct cp.Id
     ' + @ResourceClause + N'
     ) as sq
     ORDER BY ' + STUFF((SELECT N', ' + cs.SortColumn + N' ' +  cs.OrderColumn FROM @ColumnSort cs FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') +
     IIF(@s IS NOT NULL, N' OFFSET ' + cast(@p * @s as nvarchar(255)) + N' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + cast(@s as nvarchar(255)) + N' ROWS ONLY', N'')

Exec (@Query)

select @totalCount = count(*) from #Temp

-- Do Something with @totalCount
```

The above has not been tested though

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is the count of rows that will be returned by the execution of `@Query`
You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` for this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
SET @totalCount = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @totalCount
```